# Is Pentasa an immunosuppressive drug?

Tags: gastroenterology, crohns, immunosuppressant

Is Pentasa an immunosuppresive drug? I want to know because my brother has been diagnosed with Crohn's Disease.

Comment: The generic name is mesalamine. You can find an answer within minutes through search engines.

Answer (score 5):

Pentasa is one brand name for a drug called mesalazine (or mesalamine). While immunosuppressant drugs are often used on the management of Crohn’s disease, this is not one of them. It is in a group of drugs called aminosalicylates (somewhat similar to aspirin and non-steroidal anti-inflammatory drugs, but the mechanism of action is a little different).

It works through an anti-inflammatory effect on the walls of the bowel by inhibiting inflammatory compounds called prostaglandin E2 and leukotrienes. It can be administered orally or rectally, depending on the affected part of the bowel.

Here is a [link](https://patient.info/health/inflammatory-bowel-disease/crohns-disease) to a useful advice leaflet about Crohn’s disease and its treatments.

Source: [British National Formulary](https://bnf.nice.org.uk/#Search?q=Pentasa)

Comment: Pentasa is mesalamine, not sulfasalazine.

Comment: Thanks @Jan - I have edited the answer. I got the wrong name in my head when checking the BNF - not great for a doctor! :)

Comment: OK, it's mesalaMine, if you don't mind.

Comment: This might be a difference between countries and how generic drug names are used. It’s definitely mesalazine here in UK? Are you in US or Canada?

Comment: OK, I see, both versions are used.

Comment: @Jan I’m happy to add both to the answer.

Comment: "Mesalazine (INN, BAN), also known as Mesalamine (USAN)." From [DrugBank](https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/DB00244). In US it appears to be mesalamine.

Comment: Thanks @Jan - I have added that to the answer as well.